# Dynamically change a picture in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, database, image-manipulation, dynamically-generated

img src="Images/MainMaster/TruckImg.gif" id="imgCompanyLogo" alt="Company Logo" />

I have an image that i would like to change for each company that logs in to the site. 
How can i dynamically change that picture to an image stored in my database?  Thank you!

Comment: Are you wanting to change the picture after the page has loaded or as each page loads?  These are different questions with rather different solutions.  ASP.Net is referenced in the title but ASP is a tag are different technologies that you should be consistent in terms of which you are using please.

Comment: This is on the master page, and currently is displaying our company logo. What i want it to do is when the user logs in, it will display a picture  they can upload on their profile page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a dictionary that connects a log-in ID to a picture path on your databse.  At log-in (or just on PageLoad, I have no idea how your site is set up), just say:

```
string filePath = ImageTable[loginID]
imgCompanyLogo.ImageURL = filePath;
```